# PHP SQL Data Insert Issue

Tags: php, sql, dreamweaver

I have created a page of insert data into mysql database in dreamweaver using insert data wizard, now when i want to insert data its not working, even its not going to the page i want to go after insertion, please help me out, below is my code.

```
 <?php
 if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
 function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "",         $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
     {
   if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
 $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
 }

 $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
 case "text":
   $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
   break;    
 case "long":
 case "int":
    $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
  case "double":
   $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
   break;
 case "date":
   $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
 case "defined":
   $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
 }
  return $theValue;
}
}

  $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    }

   if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO users (id, `First Name`, `Last Name`, `User ID`,     Password, `Secret Question`, Answer, `Date of Birth`, Gender, Profession, Phone, `Email ID`, Address, Time_Stamp, AdminLevel) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['First_Name'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Last_Name'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['User_ID'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Password'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Secret_Question'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Answer'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Date_of_Birth'], "date"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Gender'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Profession'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Phone'], "double"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Email_ID'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Address'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Time_Stamp'], "date"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['AdminLevel'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_user, $user);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $user) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "/mashwani/thank.php";
    if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
   $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
 }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
 }

 mysql_select_db($database_user, $user);
 $query_User = "SELECT * FROM users";
$User = mysql_query($query_User, $user) or die(mysql_error());
 $row_User = mysql_fetch_assoc($User);
 $totalRows_User = mysql_num_rows($User);
 ?>
```

Comment: where is your connection defined?

Answer (score 0):

I think when you call your page value
$_POST["MM_insert"] = null or not "form1"

Too i thinks your condition is bad because if "MM_insert" has value "form1" always is true isset($_POST["MM_insert") , for this reason i only will use ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")

Your redirection 
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo)); are into the if for this reason if values the if isn't true never redirect to the page.

Execute always the next select 
$query_User = "SELECT * FROM users";
$User = mysql_query($query_User, $user) or die(mysql_error());
and not return any values because not are printed witch echo os showed with var_dump.

I advise you use var_dump($_POST["MM_insert"])

Comment: Can you please be some specific on this as I am new here and I dont know more about the coding usage in PHP please

Comment: I have put code and explication. Replace if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) { for this if ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1") {